# Convert Twitter bootstrap tabs into a select menu

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap

Anyone know how to convert Twitter Bootstrap tabs into a select menu? This would come in handy for a mobile layout.

Something like this...

```
<select>
<option value="#everything">Everything</option>
<option value="#catalog">Catalog</option>
<option value="#articles">Articles+</option>
<option value="#ejournals">E-Journals</option>
<option value="#reserve">Reserve</option>
<option value="#databases">Databases</option>
</select>
```

Here is a live example. I have tabs setup and are working. But I want it to also work with a select menu. So the select menu would change the tabs also. This would be used on the mobile version of the site.

http://library.buffalo.edu/redesign/html/tabs.html

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for this, because I was looking something like that. The snippet of Terry help me too much for accomplish that. I used jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).resize(responsive);
  $(window).trigger('resize');

});

function responsive(){

  // get resolution
  var resolution = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

  // because mobile layout
  if (resolution < 979) {

    if( $('.select-menu').length === 0 ) {

      // create select menu
      var select = $('<select></select>');

      // add classes to select menu
      select.addClass('select-menu input-block-level');

      // each link to option tag
      $('.nav-tabs li a').each(function(){
        // create element option
        var option = $('<option></option>');

        // add href value to jump
        option.val(this.href);

        // add text
        option.text($(this).text());

        // append to select menu
        select.append(option);
      });

      // add change event to select
      select.change(function(){
        window.location.href = this.value;
      });

      // add select element to dom, hide the .nav-tabs
      $('.nav-tabs').before(select).hide();

    }

  }

  // max width 979px
  if (resolution > 979) {
    $('.select-menu').remove();
    $('.nav-tabs').show();
  }

}
```

[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LACnj/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything special. If you include in your page this four files:

- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap-responsive.css <-- This is the most important for what you need. This .css file will indicate what layout follow depending on the width of the page.
- jquery-lastest-pack.js <-- Search in google: "lastest pack jquery"
- bootstrap.js

The files that are named as bootstrap will be included in the bootstrap package you have downloaded.

The navbar has to be something like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">

   <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
   <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </a>

   <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
   <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

   <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
   <div class="nav-collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the things that you include in `nav-collapse` will be included into a nice menu for mobile devices. You can read more in bootstrap documentation [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) in the subsection *"Optional responsive variation"*

If you want to see an example of how will be the final result, go to [Bootstrap Main Page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and reduce the width of your browser.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I wanted to turn the tabs into a <select> menu.

<pre>
<code>

    "<select>
    <option value="#everything">Everything</option>
    <option value="#catalog">Catalog</option>
    <option value="#articles">Articles+</option>
    <option value="#ejournals">E-Journals</option>
    <option value="#reserve">Reserve</option>
    <optionvalue="#databases">Databases</option>
    </select>"

</code>
</pre>

Comment: Ouh ok, I didn't understand the question then.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay using Javascript, you could just create a function to convert it when you determine the user is on a mobile.

```
var $select = $('<select></select>');

$('.nav-tabs li a').each(function() {
    $select.append('<option>' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBddM/