# Select drop down menu for nav on collapse

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, nav

I’m not a fan of the collapsed 3 line nav button when bootstrap collapses for smaller viewports. Is there a way to get the navbar collapse to a select drop down menu, as well as place it somewhere else on the page, other than in the top right? Just like this: http://filamentgroup.com/examples/rwd-nav-patterns/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Twitter bootstrap tabs into a select menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459392/convert-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-into-a-select-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what happens on the filamentgroup site, you can see that below a certain width, the body gets the class `nav-menu` and removes if when sized larger. This is their rwd-nav.js complete with comments:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.nav-primary')
  // test the menu to see if all items fit horizontally
  .bind('testfit', function(){
    var nav = $(this),
     items = nav.find('a');

    $('body').removeClass('nav-menu');                    

    // when the nav wraps under the logo, or when options are stacked, display the nav as a menu              
    if ( (nav.offset().top > nav.prev().offset().top) || ($(items[items.length-1]).offset().top > $(items[0]).offset().top) ) {

       // add a class for scoping menu styles
       $('body').addClass('nav-menu');
    };                    
 })

 // toggle the menu items' visiblity
 .find('h3')
   .bind('click focus', function(){
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded')
   });   

   // ...and update the nav on window events
   $(window).bind('load resize orientationchange', function(){
   $('.nav-primary').trigger('testfit');
 });

});
```

Then in their rwd-nav.css, this repositions based on width

```
/* Media queries
------------------------------ */

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .nav-primary,
  .nav-primary ul {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-primary ul {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-primary li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }   
}

@media screen and (min-width: 910px) {
  .nav-primary {
    float: right;
    clear: none;
  }   
}
```

Hope that helps!